# How to embed a chart from google sheets into a google doc C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api, google-docs-api

I am trying to update a linked chart from google sheets into a google doc. Currently I have a template doc as well as a template sheet that contains all of my graphs. I copy both templates and then update the values as needed, How can i programmatically change the sheet reference in the google doc to the new chart ID of the updated sheet? I do not see an update request type that allows this. I am using the .net client for all the google products.

Comment: Can you share your code? Samples of input? Samples of desired output? (Remember to sanitize it so no personal information is leaked)

Comment: I figured out there is no way to replace a chart via the API. Its not a currently supported update request. What I had to do, for anyone trying to do this in the future is use pictures as place holders and do a "ReplaceImageRequest" to upload a .png containing the graph. I generated the graphs using Graph.js and then invoke chrome in headless mode to take a screenshot of the graph. Wonky workaround but it seems to meet my needs.